# A word for one who is sacrificed or suffers so others need not

Tags: single-word-requests

Although the word martyr somewhat applies, it includes a nobility not necessarily present.

An idiom describing this, in a voluntary situation, would be drawing the short straw, thereby acquiring some unpleasant or dangerous duty. An idiom for an involuntary situation would be getting thrown under the bus.

### Context

**Friend:** *I knew someone would eventually need to refactor this code. I didn't think it would be me.*

**Me:** *You're our... uh, what's the word?*

Comment: I think one who gets sacrificed is just a sacrifice. I like sacrificial lamb, but it's an idiom and has religious connotations.

Comment: I think we need more context. It makes a difference whether the person being sacrificed is *willing*, for example (*whipping boys* rarely are), and whether they were "correctly" selected (not usually the implication with a *scapegoat*).

Comment: Context added, though I don't know how helpful it is. Willingness is only tangentially applicable in that it's others who give them the status. Afterward they might acquiesce or resist. Assume a reason for the selection, though not a particularly great one.

Answer (score 1):

> [**patsy**:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/patsy)
>
> 1. a person who is easily cheated, victimized, etc
> 2. a scapegoat
>
> [**cannon fodder**:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cannon-fodder)
>
> men regarded as expendable because they are part of a huge army
>
> [**pawn**:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pawn)
>
> a person, group, etc, manipulated by another

Answer (score 0):

Consider, **lifesaver**.

> : one that provides help in a crisis or emergency. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lifesaver)
>
> *Friend: I knew someone would eventually need to refactor this code. I didn't think it would be me.*
>
> *Me: You're our lifesaver*

Answer (score 0):

You could consider **saviour** as in "you are our saviour" although depending on tone and context it can also be used to imply someone who is making too much of a task that they are undertaking, *possibly*, to save others from an unpleasant task.